# calling jquery script by converting it to a fucntion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have 2 radio buttons and two normal anchor links as shown:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id='type'>
           <input type="radio" name="Single" value="Single" id="Single" checked="checked">Single
           <input type="radio" name="Single" value="Multiple" id="Multiple">Multiple
    </div> 
            <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Select files</a>
            <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success">Upload files</a><br />
            <div id="progressBar" class="tiny-green">
            <div></div>
            </div>
            <div id="showfilelist">
               <img src="images/attachment.png" id="attach" />
            </div>
</div>
```

Now I have the below script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Single').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert("Single Selected");
            }
        });

        $('#Multiple').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert("Multiple Selected");
            }
        });



      $('#progressBar').hide();
      $('#attach').hide();
            // Custom example logic
            function randomString(length) {
                var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

                if (!length) {
                    length = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
                }

                var str = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
                }
                return str;
            }
            var tempDir = randomString(8);
            document.getElementById("tempDir").value = tempDir;
            var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',

                browse_button: 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
                container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself

                url: 'Upload.ashx?random=' + tempDir,

                filters: {
                    max_file_size: '10mb',
                    mime_types: [
                        { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
                        { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
                    ]
                },

                // Flash settings
                flash_swf_url: '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',

                // Silverlight settings
                silverlight_xap_url: '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',


                init: {
                    PostInit: function () {
                        document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function () {
                            uploader.start();
                            return false;
                        };
                    },

                    FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                        $("#showfilelist").html("");
                        document.getElementById('showfilelist').innerHTML += up.files.length + " " + 'Files Selected';
                        },



                    UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
                        $('#progressBar').show();
                        progressBar(file.percent, $('#progressBar'));
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#progressBar').fadeOut();
                        }, 2000);
                    },



                    UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                        $("#showfilelist").html("");
                        document.getElementById('showfilelist').innerHTML += up.files.length + " " + 'Files Uploaded Successfully';
                    },

                    Error: function (up, err) {
                        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
                    }


                }
            });

            uploader.init();
    });
```

Scenario:

1. If I select single option radio button I need to convert this script to function namely "single" and call it when uploadfiles triggers.
2. If I select multiple option radio button I need to convert this script to another function namely "multiple" and call it when uploadfiles triggers.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 `uploader` single and multiple, and you want to make `uploadfiles` call either of them base on the radio user clicked?

Comment: Yes..I would like uploadfiles call either of them base on the radio user clicked

Comment: Let's say they named `singleUp` and `multiUp`, you can do just as what is written in `postInit`, for example change `alert("Single Selected");` to `document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function () {                             singleUp.start(); return false; };` and so do `alert("Multiple Selected");`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have 2 instances of uploader, one for single and one for multiple, then in that domready, you can first declare a variable like `activeUploader`, then make `uploadfiles` to call that instead of upload, and assign either `single` or `multiple` to active when single/multi is clicked.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Active one.
    var activeUploader = null;
    // create instances
    var singleUploader = ...; 
    var multUploader = ...;

    // If init is necessary, but you can remove that postInit part now.
    singleUploader.init();
    multUploader.init();
    // Choose one as default.
    activeUploader = singleUploader;

    document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onClick = function() {
      activeUploader.start();
      return false;
    };
    // Or you can register the click by jquery.
    // $('#uploadfiles').click(function(e) {
    //   e.preventDefault();
    //   activeUploader.start();
    // });

    $('#Single').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            activeUploader = singleUploader;
        }
    });

    $('#Multiple').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            activeUploader = multUploader;
        }
    });
});
```